# Maintain a large dictionary in memory for Django-Python?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, memcached, redis

I have a big `key-value` pair dump, that I need to lookup for my django-Python webapp.

So, I have following options:

- Store it as **json** dump and load it as a python dict.
- Store it in a **dump.py** and import the dict from it.
- Use some targeted systems for this problem: **[ Are these really meant for this usecase ? ]**

  - **Mem-cache**
  - Redis
  - Any other option ?

**Which from above is the right way to go ?**

**How will you compare memcache and redis ?**

**Update:**

- My dictionary is about **5 MB** in size and will grow over time.
- Using Redis/Memcache adds an overhead of hitting a socket every-time, so would **dump.py** will be better since it would take time to load it to memory but after that it would only do memory lookups.
- My dictionary needs to be updated every day, considering that **dump.py** will be problem, since we have to restart the django-server to reload where as I guess it would reflect on the fly in **redis and memcache**.
- One uses a system like **redis** only when you have large amount of data and you have to lookup very frequently, in that case socket gives a overhead so, how do we achieve the advantage ?

Please share your experiences on this !

Comment: Depends. Where is your bottleneck?

Comment: How often are you going to be checking the key if you are worried about sockets?

Comment: May be 1000 times per minute or even more !

Comment: You don't have to restart Django to reaload dump.py, you can use built-in `reaload()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For choosing Memcache or REDIS, they are capable of tens of thousands request per second on low-end hardware (eg. [**80,000 req/s** for REDIS on C2D Q8300](http://antirez.com/post/redis-memcached-benchmark.html)). With latencies of well below 1ms. You're saying that you're be doing something in order of 20 request a second, so performance wise it's really non-issue.

If you choose `dump.py` option, you don't need to restart Django to reload. You can make your own simple reloader:

dump.py:

```
[ dict code...]

mtime = 0
```

djago code:

```
import dump #this does nothing if it's already loaded
stat = os.stat(dump_filename)
if(stat.mtime > dump.mtime):
    reload(dump)
    dump.mtime = stat.mtime
```

---

Comment: Redis part is really informative +1 for that.
reload() is known to me, but I have reload it after every `mtime`, that takes 2 seconds to load and hangs up the page request. So, I can't take the overhead of 2 seconds every mtime - I would rather restart the server once I have my dict updated.
Anyways reloading is not the question here. Redis part is !

Comment: What you mean "for every mtime"? You've said that the dictionary is modified daily, you will have to reload it only once a day.

Comment: Ya.. here mtime is 1 day. Its fine, I said it might get updated in a day and a half. But, doesn't really matter. Redis info was important

Answer (score 2):

Memcached, though a great product, is trumped by Redis in my book.  It offers lots of things that memcached doesn't, like persistence.

It also offers more complex data structures like hashses.  What is your particular data dump?  How big is it, and how large / what type of values?

Answer (score 1):

In past for a similar problem I have used the idea of a dump.py . I would think that all of the other data structures would require a layer to convert objects of one kind into   python objects . However I would still think that this would depend on data size and the amount of data you are handling . Memcache and redis should have better indexing and look up when it comes to really large data sets and things like regex based lookup . So my recommendation would be

json -- if you are serving the data over http to some other service
python file - if data structure is not too large and you need not any special kind of look ups

memcache and redis -- if the data becomes really large

Answer (score 1):

5Mb isn't that large. You could keep it in memory in process, and I recommend that you do, until it becomes clear from profiling and testing that that approach isn't meeting your needs. Always do the simplest thing possible.

Socket communication doesn't of itself introduce much of an overhead. You could probably pare it back a little by using a unix domain socket. In any case, if you're not keeping your data in process, you're going to have to talk over some kind of pipe.

Comment: Agreed.. so do you think redis should be used if the lookups are like 5 every page loads and total 100 page loads every minute ?

Comment: @YugalJindle No, I think you should keep your data in process until such time as actual profiling shows that it is causing a problem.